# Is there any way to detect cpu/battery temperature on Android 7.0+ platform in Unity?

Tags: unity

I tried [WeTest](https://wetest.qq.com/) but it's not working because my test device is Android 8.1. Also, I tried [Emmagee](https://github.com/NetEase/Emmagee) however it's just working on Android 6.0 and below. Is there any other thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Unity Android Sensor Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android)
 I made an Android plugin for Unity and successfully printed battery temperature. Due to the privacy of my company, I can't give the code I made but if you are interested in building Android plugin for Unity, I recommend [Get temperature of battery on android](https://github.com/kshoji/Unity-Android-Sensor-Plugin) to begin.

Comment: This answer would be better if it named the resources it was linking to ("this" could be anything) and included a quick summary of the relevant info you hope a reader will glean from that source. That way, the information is easier to find and a bit more robust against link rot or changes to the linked sites.